# How to see vm.max_map_count and fs.file-max on Mac(Catalina) terminal

Tags: macos

I'm trying to view the  `vm.max_map_count` and `fs.file-max` commands output on terminal of Mac Catalina operating system. But it doesn't work. Can i know the way to view it?

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H1323
```

```
$ sysctl vm.max_map_count
sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count'
$ sysctl fs.file-max
sysctl: unknown oid 'fs.file-max'
```

Also let me know to set these values permanently on Mac, which files i need to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Linux-specific settings (see the documentation for [`vm.max_map_count`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#max-map-count) and [`fs.file-max-nr`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#file-max-file-nr)).

On macOS, the equivalent for `fs.file-max-nr` is `kern.maxfiles`. I don’t know if there’s an equivalent for `vm.max_map_count`.

To change these values permanently, add them to `/etc/sysctl.conf`; in some cases you might need to make other changes, see [Why won't kern.maxfiles setting in /etc/sysctl.conf stick?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168495/203966)

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen.